# Grafana volumeMount error when using minikube

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, istio

I am trying to do a small POC by using minikube and istio.
However, when adding the deployments I have an error on grafana:

`failed to prepare subPath for volumeMount "config" of container "grafana"`

The version used is grafana/grafana:5.2.3. Does someone has a clue how this can be solved?
My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.
Thanks!

Comment: can you share yaml you used to deploy grafana?

Comment: Hello @EmruzHossain, just restarted the pods and the problem dissapeared.